# Symfony MakerBundle Documentation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I want to understand how should I use the makerBundle, but i can't find any documentation that explain each component...

I searched the [bundle description](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html)
the [introducing](https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-maker-bundle)
and the [github](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle)

But it's not really clear, we don't understand the behavior of each components, I know that i can search in the github of course but i would like to be sure that the big documentation doesn't exist before :D

Thank's !

PS: I'm using Symfony 4

Comment: Hi Alexandre, what kind of help do you need ? It's just command to execute. Symfony is OSS so every contribution for updating documentation is welcome :-)

Comment: I want to know how should i use each maker with some examples

Answer (score 2):

from the docs

> The names of the commands are self-explanatory, but some of them include optional arguments and options. Check them out with the --help option:

`php bin/console make:controller --help`

Comment: Yes, for a controller it's self-explanatory you say true, but for unit-test, validator, voter or some others it's harder to understand there goals and there applications cases

Comment: @AlexandreCorvino well, there are no more examples. I think you can check all available options for commands. And run them one by one and check what is generated. I think MakerBundle just generates simple skeletons, that's why documentation is not needed.

Comment: I think that i will do that and browse the github thank's anyway ^^